# How do I recover deleted svn-base files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I ran a "helpful" script that deleted a bunch of files from my .svn directories.  Now, when I try to do an update or revert or whatever, I get errors saying the files are missing.

How can I recover from this?  The svn repository is huge, so I'd rather avoid having to delete the whole working folder and get it again.

Comment: how big is the folder that has the deleted .svn files (not the whole repo or the checked out folder) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you will export it then you can checkout over it and it will version existing files instead of downloading them. If you fail to export correctly run a script that deletes all .svn folders

Comment: I am trying this, but the checkout, though saying "versioned" seems to be downloading quite a bit.

Comment: By default it should only version existing files and leave modified files in "red" state.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using TortoiseSVN.  It is still doing the "checkout".  Doesn't SVN keep a backup of the files in the .svn directory?  By exporting, it deleted the .svn directories, meaning that it has to redownload everything, right?

Comment: No it's like during the initial import. When you first import your project it's unversioned until you checkout. When you checkout on top of your unversioned project the default behavior is to create a working copy by versioning existing items instead of downloading them.